# Can 人 be used without a measure word?

Tags: grammar, usage

I have seen sentences like 我们学校有500人。

Why doesn't it have a measure word?

Can 人 appear without a measure word like the words 年 and 天?

Comment: 人 can function as a measure (of any body of people,school,class,prison population size)

Comment: also 人次 bkrs：#2909 person-times
visits
classifier for number of people participating 
    若干次人数的总和。
如：「上个月出国观光人次突破百万。」（similarly 架次，千瓦小时）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in many cases, the measure word 个 is omitted.

Examples:

> 我校有五百人，其中三人是转校生。
>   这起事故造成两人死亡，四人重伤，七人失踪。
>   这个活动吸引了近万人参加。
>   七十人投了票，二十人弃权。

However, the omission of 个 usually means formality. That means we omit it when we talk in a formal way, eg. report news. But when we talk casually with friends, we tend to add 个:

> 我们学校有五百个人，三个是转来的。
>   这个车祸，死了两个人，四个人受伤，还有七个人失踪了。
>   差不多有一万个人参加了这个活动。
>   七十个人投票了，还有二十个弃权了。

Comment: Is the omission of any measure word a trace of formality?

Comment: No, the omission of a measure word doesn't necessarily show formality in other cases. Generally, the omission of a measure word is just incorrect.